# convert string value to integer in Django template

Tags: django, if-statement, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

In home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Select products:</h3>
            <form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'home' %}">
                
                <select name="parameters" data-placeholder="Choose products" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
                    {% for p in productnames %}
                        {% if k == p %}
                            <option value="{{ p.productnames }}" selected> {{ p.productnames }} </option>
                        {% else%} 
                            <option value="{{ p.id }}"> {{ p.productnames }} </option>
                            
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select><br/>
                <label for="submit"></label><button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div><br />
        <h3> Distribution of sales in the products:</h3>
    </div>
</div>
{% for p in productList %}
    {% for pin in productnames %}
        <p>{{pin.id}}  {{p}}</p>
        {% if p == pin.id %}
            <p>exists</p>
        {% else %} 
            <p>not exist</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<p>{{ productList }}</p>
```

**in this html file 'p' always returns a string value for ex: it returns like '10' instead of 10. all i want is to convent this '10' to 10 or convert returned other p_in value to 10 to '10'.**

in views.py

```
def productList(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    p = request.GET.get('parameters')
    print(p)
    #k = request.GET('parameters[]')
    productnames = Products.objects.all()
    context = {
        'productList': p, 'productnames': productnames,
    }
       


return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I tried to convert the values of the p in product list to integer. because it dosen't mactch the format with pin.id

Comment: how does your model look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views.py

```
def productList(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    p = request.GET.getlist('parameters')
    print(p)
    #k = request.GET('parameters[]')
    productnames = Products.objects.all()
    context = {
        'productList': p, 'productnames': productnames,
    }
    # --- logic later for chart ------    


return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

In home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Select products:</h3>
            <form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'home' %}">
                
                <select name="parameters" data-placeholder="Choose products" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
                    {% for p in productnames %}
                        {% if k == p %}
                            <option value="{{ p.productnames }}" selected> {{ p.productnames }} </option>
                        {% else%} 
                            <option value="{{ p.id }}"> {{ p.productnames }} </option>
                            
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select><br/>
                <label for="submit"></label><button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div><br />
        <h3> Distribution of sales in the products:</h3>
    </div>
</div>
{% for p in productList %}
    {% for pin in productnames %}
        <p>{{pin.id|stringformat:"s"}}  {{p}}</p>
        {% if p == pin.id|stringformat:"s" %}
            <p>exists</p>
        {% else %} 
            <p>not exist</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<p>{{ productList }}</p>
```

> **Note** `{{value|stringformat:"s"}}` can be used to convert `integer value` to `string value`

Answer (score 0):

You filter the queryset in the template using `if-else` which is not ideal. Instead you should perform this filtering in the view itself. Also your `parameters` is a select tag which may have multiple selected values yet you use `.get('parameters')` which will only give you one value instead you should use the [`getlist` method [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) of the QueryDict:

```
def productList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET': # Do you even need to check this? You appear to only use a GET request...
        p = request.GET.getlist('parameters')
        productnames = Products.objects.all()
        filtered_products = Products.objects.filter(pk__in=p)
        context = {
            'productList': p, 'productnames': productnames, 'filtered_products': filtered_products
        }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

In the template your loop would simply become:

```
{% for product in filtered_products %}
    {{ product.productnames }}
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: You should use a form class instead of manually making a form. See [Building a form in
> Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).
> Also a models name should be singular hence instead of
> <s>`Products`</s> you should name it **`Product`**. In general in
> your code you also break various naming conventions in Python, I would
> suggest you to look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. This is really helpful.

p = request.GET.getlist('parameters')  solved my part of the problem 
Thank you once again..!!